# P/Invoking CreateToolhelp32Snapshot failing in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

Hey, im doing a little app for my smart phone, using Windows Mobile 6. I'm trying to get all currently running processec, but method CreateToolhelp32Snapshot always returns -1. So now im stuck. I tried to get error with invoking GetLastError() method, but that method returns 0 value.
Here is a snippet of my code.

```
private const int TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 0x00000002;
[DllImport("toolhelp.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(uint flags, 
                                                     uint processid);

public static Process[] GetProcesses()
    {
        ArrayList procList = new ArrayList();
        IntPtr handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

        if ((int)handle > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                PROCESSENTRY32 peCurr;
                PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = new PROCESSENTRY32();

                // get byte array to pass to API call
                byte[] peBytes = pe32.ToByteArray();
                // get the first process
                int retval = Process32First(handle, peBytes);
```

Comment: "if ((int)handle > 0)" is incorrect; you should use "if ( handle != -1 )". Is your statement that CreateToolhelp32Snapshot always returns -1 literally true, or are you saying it based on your code as posted? You may be getting a valid handle which fails your test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First, your handle check is wrong.  It's common for the high bit to be on in a handle, causing it to look like a negative number when cast to a signed int.  You should be checking that is isn't NULL (0) or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (-1 / 0xffffffff).
- You shouldn't be "invoking GetLastError" but calling Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
- You've not set the SetLastError attribute in the P/Invoke declaration.  In C# it defaults to false, in VB it defaults to true.
- Where's your PROCESS32 implementation?  The [docs clearly state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915359.aspx) that the dwLength member must be set before the call and it's not clear here if that's happening.

As a side note, the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.smartdeviceframework.com)'s [OpenNETCF.ToolHelp namespace](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/a2bccceb-fc28-262d-c05c-26565a0986d1.htm) has all of this implemented and working (in case you'd rather not reinvent the wheel).

Comment: OpenNETCF.ToolHelp does not work for me. It throws "Unable to create snapshot". Fortunately, [ProcessCE class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36841/Compact-Framework-Process-class-that-supports-full) does the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
```

use

```
private const int TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS = 0x40000000;
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS | TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS, 0);
```

By default CreateToolhelp32Snapshot will try to snapshot the heaps and that can cause an out of memory error.

Found this at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e91d845d-d51e-45ad-8acf-737e832c20d0/createtoolhelp32snapshot-windows-mobile-5?forum=vssmartdevicesnative and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing valid "last error" information, perhaps you might need to add the "SetLastError" attribute on the API's DllImport attribute ([MSDN reference with code examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror.aspx)).  According to the documentation of this attribute, you should set SetLastError to...

> ...true to indicate that the callee will
>   call SetLastError; otherwise, false.
>   The default is false.
>
> The runtime marshaler calls
>   GetLastError and caches the value
>   returned to prevent it from being
>   overwritten by other API calls. You
>   can retrieve the error code by calling
>   GetLastWin32Error

As for the API failure you're seeing, I don't spot anything obvious offhand; the code you have seems very similar to the sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446560.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper implementation based on the MSDN documentation

```c#
private const int INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

[Flags]
private enum SnapshotFlags : uint
{
    HeapList = 0x00000001,
    Process = 0x00000002,
    Thread = 0x00000004,
    Module = 0x00000008,
    Module32 = 0x00000010,
    Inherit = 0x80000000,
    All = 0x0000001F,
    NoHeaps = 0x40000000
}

[DllImport("toolhelp.dll"]
private static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags dwFlags, int th32ProcessID);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PROCESSENTRY32
{
    public uint dwSize;
    public uint cntUsage;
    public uint th32ProcessID;
    public IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
    public uint th32ModuleID;
    public uint cntThreads;
    public uint th32ParentProcessID;
    public int pcPriClassBase;
    public uint dwFlags;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)] public string szExeFile;
};


IntPtr hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags.Process, 0);

if (hSnap.ToInt64() != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry = new PROCESSENTRY32();
    procEntry.dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESSENTRY32));

    if (Process32First(hSnap, ref procEntry))
    {
        do
        {

            //do whatever you want here

        } while (Process32Next(hSnap, ref procEntry));
    }
}

CloseHandle(hSnap);
```

Most importantly is this line, because you must set the size of the procEntry:

`procEntry.dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESSENTRY32));`