# Determining the parent process id from C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I would like to determine the process id of the parent process for an arbitrary process in Windows.

I need this method to work on both x64 and x32.

Any ideas / sample code to make this happen. System.Diagnositics.Process does not include this info.

I am a bit worried about using the toolhelp apis cause they are 32 bit specific.

Related info:

- [C++ implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ParentPID.aspx)
- [Some thing I googled](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=27395) (the interop there is not x64 freindly)

The Performance counter solution in [the FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569609.aspx): 
(PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process ID", procName);)  scares me, cause it does not allow you to enter a process id, instead you specify a process by name so it all can go pear shape when you have multiple children.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way) has a code example in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WIN32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx) has processid and parent processid.  Getting the WMI data on 64-bit is a bit more difficult, [but still possible by changing the provider flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393067(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: yeah System.Management is a much easier path to take

Answer (score -1):

Use NAPI (Win32 FAQ)

Comment: That's a very poor answer.