# Getting the starting shortcut in c#

Tags: c#, shortcut

Lets say that I have an executable and when it is started I want to know how it's started. I.e. I would like to know if it is started with a shortcut or directly.
With this:

```
string test = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
```

I can get the path of the executable, but this is always the same, even if it's started by a shortcut.

Lets say my executable is named c:\text.exe and I start it directly, then test = 'c:\test.exe'
If I create a shortcut i.e. c:\shortcut.lnk (with target c:\test.exe) I want test to be 'c:\shortcut.exe' but it is 'c:\test.exe'

I strongly suspect this to be impossible because the OS handles the shortcut part and the executable never can see the difference, but maybe someone has a creative idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work in general, but if you are creating the shortcut, you could add a command line parameter to identify it.

Comment: Simple, but this trigged an idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicions are correct, with the operating system hiding the mechanics from you.

It is possible to [get the process that started you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125958/how-do-i-discover-how-my-process-was-started), however. this won't help you differentiate whether you were started from a link in the start menu, vs. being doubled clicked on in the explorer window though.