# Get shortcut responsible for launching my process

Tags: c#, process, console

I'm creating a console application (C#), and I want to know if it's possible to get the path of the shortcut that launched my console application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question was already asked here, please take a look at [Getting the starting shortcut in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513920/getting-the-starting-shortcut-in-c) to get the (only) possible way of doing this

Comment: How do you know it's the "only" way?

Comment: If there is an other way, it will probably be much more difficult to complete. So, let's say its the only way I know of