# Get handle from a main process

Tags: multithreading, delphi, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine the parent process of the current app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857037/determine-the-parent-process-of-the-current-app)

I would like to get the a MainProcess Handle or PID of a process.
For example Google Chrome drops another processes for each tab which are actually threads.
In ProcessExplorer it shows chrome.exe in the treeview as a mainprocess and the threads underneath it. How could I check or get the MainProcess Handle/PID? Something like a WindowsAPI?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@RRUZ has already answered an [almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857037/determine-the-parent-process-of-the-current-app) on Stack Overflow. However, the code there is incorrect in that it declares process IDs as `THandle`. The following corrects the mistakes that I found, and also adapts the routine to return a PID rather than a filename:

```
uses
  Windows,
  tlhelp32,
  SysUtils;

function GetParentPid: DWORD;
var
  HandleSnapShot: THandle;
  EntryParentProc: TProcessEntry32;
  CurrentProcessId: DWORD;
  HandleParentProc: THandle;
  ParentProcessId: DWORD;
begin
  Result := 0;
  HandleSnapShot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);   //enumerate the process
  if HandleSnapShot<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    EntryParentProc.dwSize := SizeOf(EntryParentProc);
    if Process32First(HandleSnapShot, EntryParentProc) then    //find the first process
    begin
      CurrentProcessId := GetCurrentProcessId; //get the id of the current process
      repeat
        if EntryParentProc.th32ProcessID=CurrentProcessId then
        begin
          ParentProcessId := EntryParentProc.th32ParentProcessID; //get the id of the parent process
          HandleParentProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, False, ParentProcessId);
          if HandleParentProc<>0 then
          begin
            Result := ParentProcessId;
            CloseHandle(HandleParentProc);
          end;
          break;
        end;
      until not Process32Next(HandleSnapShot, EntryParentProc);
    end;
    CloseHandle(HandleSnapShot);
  end;
end;
```

I know that this is a duplicate question, but the code here is precisely what the OP wants, so I'll leave it visible for a while at least.

Comment: since which you are removed the call to `GetModuleFileNameEx` function to get the parent process filename you can remove the `Psapi` unit too of the uses.

Comment: @RRUZ Thank you. Done. Probably SysUtils can go too.

Comment: DWORD is better than THandle, but when I wrote that article i use  Delphi 2007 Where  `THandle = System.THandle = DWORD = LongWord` :)

Comment: @RRUZ Yeah, I know where you are coming from. The thing is, `THandle` was never really equal to `DWORD`. It has always been a pointer sized thing. In winnt.h it is `typedef PVOID HANDLE`. It's getting these details right that makes porting to 64 bit easy. Now, the RTL has traditionally been rather poor at these details which I think is where a lot of the mis-understandings arise from. `THandle` has traditionally been declared as `LongWord` which is just bogus in my view. It should be `Pointer`.