# Find out name of invoking process in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get parent process in .NET in managed way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way)

I have an C# executable file that's invoked from another C# executable file. Is there a way to determine the name of the executable that invoked the executable that is currently running? I imagine there must be some way, but am having trouble Googling this. I imagine I must be using the wrong terminology.

Comment: Isn't there Assembly.GetCallingAssembly - not sure if this works across AppDomains...

Comment: you could give the second exe a parameter with the data you need.

Comment: @elyashiv Unfortunately specs require no command line parameters. :(

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857037/determine-the-parent-process-of-the-current-app the question's tagged delphi, but the method is in the Windows API and so is usable in .NET as well.

Comment: One thing to understand: using Process.Start will, by default, give the command to the Windows Shell to execute, creating a "top-level process" not considered to be the "child" of the caller. You must override this behavior using a ProcessStartInfo structure to define the parameters of the invocation, and set UseShellExecute to false.