# Programmatically determine if .NET WinForms application launched via debugger or not

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I would like to know if there is a programmatic way of determining at run-time if the application was launched via the debugger or by launching an installed version of the application. My app is currently being deployed via ClickOnce.

There are certain settings I would like to alter when the app is run in debug mode vs production mode.

I am aware of the build configurations solution -- I am curious if there is a programmatic way to determine this information

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way? Except in your case, see if the parent process is a debugger (devenv, cdb, windbg).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx).

It is a static method within the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, as you can deduce from the name, it will return true if the debugger is attached (whether it was attached *after* launch or not).

You can put this in the application entry point (`main`) in order to find out if the application was lauched with a debugger attached, but keep in mind that it can be attached at a later time.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about being attached later, though in this case that is not a concern

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, you can use [Debugger.IsAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx). However, be aware that this doesn't necessarily mean that the application was **launched** by the debugger, it may have been launched normally and then a debugger was attached to the process (I don't know if the difference is relevant for you).

Answer (score 1):

To tell if it has been launched in the VS Debugger:

if(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainManager.ToString().ToLower().Contains("vshost") == true)

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [Debugger.IsAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx)

The [Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kzs2ysh.aspx) class is a class worth looking at. It contains some nice goodies.