# Get Application File Path in Windows Forms Application

Tags: asp.net, winforms

I have a simple windows form app that I need to get the file path for. I am placing a config file in the same directory and I need to be able to get the path to that file.

I have used 
`Application.CommonAppDataPath`
but that returns the path with 1.0.0.0 at the end.

and 
`Applicaiton.StartupPath`
but that returns the path with \bin\debug at the end

Is there anyway to get the path to just the main file directory without anything appended to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.StartupPath` is returning the path with `\bin\debug` on the end because that ***is*** where your code is running, at least on your development machine.

If you are going to deploy this away from your development machine then `Application.StartupPath` will give you what you're asking for - the file path for your application. And yes, if you have deployed the config file to that same location, your code is going to find it.

How to get the application also working on your development machine and get round the `bin\debug` issue? Well, a dirty hack would be just to chop the `bin\debug` string off the end of `Application.StartupPath`.

In that case, if you need to check for whether you're running inside the debugger, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832402/programmatically-determine-if-net-winforms-application-launched-via-debugger-or)

Comment: Or, just copy the config file into `bin\debug`, rather than creating greasy debug-only code...

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Dim aPath As String 
Dim aName As String 

aName = _
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly. _
  GetModules()(0).FullyQualifiedName    

aPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(aName)
```

Comment: This gives GetExecutingAssembly() is a method which is not valid in the given context

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`Application.ExecutablePath;` which gives full path including executable file name
and

`Application.StartupPath;` for your current running application path directory without file name