# Process Tree using .Net c# yworks deviare

Tags: c#, .net, process

I want to achieve something like the process tree by process monitor. To display the relation of the process via tree.

I am not sure on how to determine the root process (as some of the process did had a PPID, but process monitor had it on as the root)

I am using yWorks + Deviare + visual studio 2008 + c#.

Any help or guidance please :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps? [How to get parent process in .NET in managed way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way)