# send file of unknown type to "open with" dialog

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file

In my application I have a saved file path which I use to try and open the file.
I am using something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

If the file has an associated default program this works fine.
My question is regarding the scenario where the file does not have an associated default program.

In that case, I want to use the "open with" option ,  where I can choose a program from a list, or search the web.
This is available if I open the context menu of the file with the mouse:
[image]

Is it possible to do this programmatically?

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer here:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/657117-opening-file-unknown-extension

and here:

[detect selected program opened using openas_rundll in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718855/detect-selected-program-opened-using-openas-rundll-in-c-sharp)

Merged solution works fine:

```
 try
    {
  string path = @"c:\install.res.1028.dll";
    ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
    Process.Start(pInfo );
    }
    catch (Win32Exception ex)
    {
    if (ex.ErrorCode == -2147467259)
    //ErrorCode for No application is associated with
    the specified file for
    //this operation
    {

            Process.Start("rundll32.exe", string.Format("shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL \"{0}\"", path));
    }
    }
```

Comment: Note that `OpenAs_RunDLL` is undocumented and [does not always work.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566667/rundll32-shell32-dll)

Answer (score 0):

If you call Start with a file that has unrecognised extension, you'll get the standard "Windows can't open this file" dialogue.  From there, if the user elects to "Select a program from the list of installed programs," they then see the same dialogue as when you click "Choose default program..." in your menu screenshot.

Alternatively, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224693/how-can-i-display-the-open-with-dialog-for-an-unregistered-file-extension) regarding explicitly displaying the "Open with" dialogue.

Comment: I will check again, but I'm pretty sure I got an exception. Maybe this dialog is shown as part of the FileDialog ? I'm opening the file with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start , because I don't need the user to chhose a file , I already know the path. thanks

Comment: Your link was helpful, only in Delphi. I found a similar solution in C#. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

If your question is to register a file type (the file extension to be exact), you may use this.
I use it successfully in my application installer.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a file type. This enables users to open a file via double-clicking in the windows explorer. 
    /// ATTENTION: Providing a wrong extension or fileType will certainly cause a malfunction of other file types!!!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="extension"> The file extension (this may contain a starting '.') </param>
    /// <param name="fileType"> Name of the file type. </param>
    /// <param name="fileDescription"> Descriptive text for the file type. Displayed in the windows explorer. </param>
    /// <param name="verb"> Verb to use, usually 'open' </param>
    /// <param name="commandLine"> Commandline for the 'open' verb. Example: "C:\Zeiss\CmmCtrl\bin\ScriptTool.exe %1". You may use quotes ("") if any argument contains whitespaces. Don't forget to use a %1, which is replaced  </param>
    public static void RegisterFileType(string extension, string fileType, string fileDescription, string verb, string commandLine) {
        RegisterFileType(extension, fileType, fileDescription, verb, commandLine, "", -1);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a file type. This enables users to open a file via double-clicking in the windows explorer. 
    /// ATTENTION: Providing a wrong extension or fileType will certainly cause a malfunction of other file types!!!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="extension"> The file extension (this may contain a starting '.') </param>
    /// <param name="fileType"> Name of the file type. </param>
    /// <param name="fileDescription"> Descriptive text for the file type. Displayed in the windows explorer. </param>
    /// <param name="verb"> Verb to use, usually 'open' </param>
    /// <param name="programPath"> Full path to the program to open the file. You may use quotes ("") if any argument contains whitespaces. Example: "C:\Zeiss\CmmCtrl\bin\ScriptTool.exe" </param>
    /// <param name="arguments"> Commandline for the 'open' verb. Don't forget to use a "%1". You may use quotes ("") if any argument contains whitespaces. Example: "%1"</param>
    /// <param name="iconIndex"> Index of the icon within the executable. Use -1 if not used. </param>
    public static void RegisterFileType(string extension, string fileType, string fileDescription, string verb, string programPath, string arguments, int iconIndex) {
        if (!extension.StartsWith(".")) extension = "." + extension;

        RegistryKey key;
        string commandLine = programPath + " " + arguments;

        // 1) Extension
        //    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zzz=zzzFile
        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(extension);
        key.SetValue("", fileType);
        key.Flush();

        // 2) File type
        //    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\zzzFile=ZZZ File
        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(fileType);
        key.SetValue("", fileDescription);
        key.Flush();

        // 3) Action (verb)
        //    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\zzzFile\shell\open\command=Notepad.exe %1
        //    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\zzzFile\shell\print\command=Notepad.exe /P %1
        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(fileType + "\\shell\\" + verb + "\\command");
        key.SetValue("", commandLine);
        key.Flush();

        // 4) Icon
        if (iconIndex >= 0) {
            key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(fileType + "\\DefaultIcon");
            key.SetValue("", programPath + "," + iconIndex.ToString());
            key.Flush();
        }

        // 5) Notify running applications
        SHChangeNotify(SHChangeNotifyEventID.SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    /// <summary> Notifies the system of an event that an application has performed. An application should use this function if it performs an action that may affect the Shell. </summary>
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void SHChangeNotify(SHChangeNotifyEventID wEventId, SHChangeNotifyFlags uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);
```

Use `"open"` for `verb`.
When providing a file name as argument, use `"\"%1\"` for `arguments`.

Comment: Thanks , but this is not what I want to do. I just want to show the open with dialog to the user , so he can select a program to open the file with.