# Program was started by user or scheduler?

Tags: vb.net, environment-variables, scheduler

Is there any way to find out, if an console-application (VB.net) was started by a user or the windows scheduler.

There´s a very similar thread, but no result:
http://www.44342.com/visual-basic-f948-t16091-p1.htm

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but wouldn't it be easiest to launch the application with some argument when running as a scheduled task?

If you don't want to use argument you can base the detection on information about [**parent process**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336322/1332034). E.g. name of the parent process will be 'svchost' when running from scheduler.

```
if(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Parent().ProcessName == "svchost")
{ 
    // Run once
}
else
{
    // Loop
}
```

Comment: And what are you looking for? Why is looking at the parent process not sufficient for you?

Comment: That´s not what i´m looking for. Background: The application loops when started by a user, but should not loop and only run once when started by scheduler, because the scheduler hat it´s own interval / trigger. Im looking for a SIMPLE and SOLID way, to find out whether it´s been started by user or scheduler.

Comment: I've modified my answer and I still think that the originally proposed solution is pretty reliable.

Comment: (The Parent() method can be found on the page linked in the second paragraph.)

Comment: That´s C#? I use VB.NET. So i changed it to "System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName". While the scheduler is running, the function returns the username. I watched the taskmanager while the scheduler is working, but it doesn´t show a "svhost"-process... *frustrated*

Comment: Please read my answer properly. It's essential that you use information from PARENT process. To do that, read the article I linked within my post. For conversion C# to VB.NET use http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: If you need to start debugger in the "scheduled" mode. Use Debugger.Launch() in your code.

Comment: You´re right @rocky. Sorry. I haven´t noticed the link in your post when i read it first. I already tried to convert that using developerfusion.com in the meanwhile, but it doesn´t work. i get two errors in visual studio. from one problem to three others... ;)

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard ;) There are no special constructs aside from extension method. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)

Comment: Ohhh... that´s is too much for my head and this time of day. I will go on  "puzzle" tomorrow. Many thanks for your help up to this point Petr!