# C#: What program is using a process

Tags: c#, process

Is there a way to see what programs are using a specific process in C#.

For example, if you're running multiple processes that are reliant upon the *javaw* process, is there a way to retreive their names?

Comment: What does it mean to be reliant on another process?

Comment: You are after a parent process, perhaps?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, though may need `Windows Management Instrumentation` APIs. Simply get `All processes`, then the `loaded Dlls` in each process, to know the libraries invoking JVM, else JavaW.exe will be a  separate process

Comment: Thank you @Andez , your solution worked great!