# How to get the caller exe file path from my C# application?

Tags: c#, shell, path, execute

My C# application is going to be executed by another exe file. When my application is loaded, I need to get the calling exe file path.

I can get my own application path by following code;

```
  Application.ExecutablePath;
```

But how to get the caller exe path? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The executable  path of the process who called `CreateProcess` that started your application ?

Comment: How is it "called"? Is it used like a lib or via `Process.Start()` ?

Comment: Michael Randall The caller application is not owned by me. So I'am not able to pass it's path to my application. Any idea?

Comment: Fildor,  I think it is called using Process.Start()

Comment: Get the `parent process` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way) and retrieve its path.

Comment: ^^ Mind to look into [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346055/982149) over the accepted one.

Comment: The code by Simon Mourier given me the IDE path on debugging, but compiled code returns null value when called by other exe. what may be the cause?

Comment: Fildor, Axel Kemper  I think the caller exe is exiting before the code executes. What may be the alternative methods?